# kernel panic - get log

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, logs, ethernet, kernel-panic

My system keeps hanging every several hours.
I think the problem is somehow connected with network, because plugging ethernet cable eliminates the problem (even if ethernet is used locally only). If I try to use WiFi without ethernet plugged - system hangs in couple of hours.

- I see no common pattern in kernel logs after it. If I am getting the idea right - it means that system can't write to HDD at that moment?
- I can't use netconsole, because my wifi doesn't support spooling and with ethernet plugged problem doesn't show itself.
- If I leave terminal opened - it fades to black after error so gives
  no information.

  How can I diagnose and eleminate the problem in such situation?

Comment: terminal should not become blank if you do the following: login to the first terminal (alt-F1), then run `setterm -blank 0; setterm -powersave off; setterm -powerdown 0`. Alternatively, if you have a parallel port and a printer to connect to it, the kernel can be configured to send console output to the printer. A serial port can also be used.

Comment: @wurtel , thanks. Sorry, misinformation about terminal - it actually doesn't hang in this mode. It's a lenovo g565 notebook, and my printer is out of order :(